# While trying to load data using DSE graphloader I am getting the error - DSE Graph not configured to process queries

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I am using the DSE Graphloader to load data from a CSV file to the DSE Graph.

I did the following steps to load the data –

**Created the graph:**

```
system.graph('followTopic').create()
```

**Set the Alias:**

```
:remote config alias g followTopic.g
```

**Create the following schema:**

```
schema.propertyKey("id").Text().single().create()
schema.propertyKey("follower").Text().single().create()
schema.propertyKey("name").Text().single().create()
schema.propertyKey("type").Text().single().create()
schema.propertyKey("followed").Text().single().create()
schema.propertyKey("timestamp").Timestamp().single().create()
schema.vertexLabel("record").partitionKey("id").create()
schema.vertexLabel("user").properties("name").create()`
```

**Mappings file:**

```
// CONFIGURATION

// Configures the data loader to create the schema
config create_schema: false, load_new: true, load_threads: 3

// DATA INPUT
// Define the data input source (a file which can be specified via command    line arguments)
// inputfiledir is the directory for the input files

inputfiledir = '/home/adminuser/data/'
followTopic = File.csv(inputfiledir + "follow.csv").delimiter(',')

//Specifies what data source to load using which mapper (as defined inline)

load(followTopic).asVertices {
   label "record"
   key "id"
}
```

**The CSV I used is:**

```
id,follower,followed,type,timestamp
1,@20cburns,topic_/best-friend,topic,5/7/2016 11:03:42 PM +00:00
2,@68,topic_/tears-fall,topic,5/3/2016 2:20:01 AM +00:00
3,@abba,topic_/best-friend,topic,6/15/2016 4:08:24 PM +00:00
…
```

**Then on running the graphloader command I get the below mentioned error -**

```
./graphloader ../followTopinMapping.groovy -filename ../follow.csv -graph followTopic -address localhost
```

**Exception Error Message:**

```
2016-08-22 14:18:00 ERROR DataLoaderImpl:519 - Graph driver attempts   exceeded for this operation, logging failure, but no records are present (may have been a schema operation)
com.datastax.dsegraphloader.exception.TemporaryException:      com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: DSE Graph not    configured to process queries
at    com.datastax.dsegraphloader.impl.loader.driver.DseGraphDriverImpl.executeGraphQuery(DseGraphDriverImpl.java:71)
at  com.datastax.dsegraphloader.impl.loader.driver.DseGraphDriverImpl.executeGraphQuery(DseGraphDriverImpl.java:87)
at com.datastax.dsegraphloader.impl.loader.driver.DseGraphDriverImpl.getSchema(DseGraphDriverImpl.java:128)
at com.datastax.dsegraphloader.impl.loader.driver.SafeGraphDriver.lambda$tryGetSchema$14(SafeGraphDriver.java:94)
at com.datastax.dsegraphloader.impl.loader.DataLoaderImpl.execute(DataLoaderImpl.java:194)
at com.datastax.dsegraphloader.impl.loader.DataLoaderBuilder.execute(DataLoaderBuilder.java:101)
at com.datastax.dsegraphloader.cli.Executable.execute(Executable.java:69)
at com.datastax.dsegraphloader.cli.Executable.main(Executable.java:163)
```

Regarding the error message **“DSE Graph not configured to process queries”** *what do I need to make the configuration for DSE Graph loader to load the data in DSE Graph?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got help from DataStax guys on this to get this working.

Actually some settings were messed up on the cluster so we just created a new cluster and then just did one setting to enable the DSE Graph service on the nodes of this cluster in the /etc/default/dse file-

```
GRAPH_ENABLED=1
```

After that updated the schema as -

```
schema.propertyKey("id").Text().single().create()
schema.propertyKey("follower").Text().single().create()
schema.propertyKey("name").Text().single().create()
schema.propertyKey("type").Text().single().create()
schema.propertyKey("followed").Text().single().create()
schema.propertyKey("timestamp").Timestamp().single().create()
schema.vertexLabel("record").partitionKey("id").properties("follower", "name", "type", "followed", "timestamp").create()
```

Also regarding TimeStamp should be a number value for it to be successfully loaded via DSE Graphloader.

After these changes I am able to successfully load the Data via DSE Graphloader.